# I don't understand the specific variable type or type of utilization I should have when trying to get this array issue to work

Tags: java, arrays, printing, syntax-error

I'm trying to get num to create multiple scenarios and get 10 inputed variables from the user which I will then utilize to print out. Once the variables are printed out I need to average them but I got stuck. Could you give me some tips?

```
final static int num = 10;
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main (String[]args)
{
    int[] list = new int [num];
    for(int i = 0; i<=num; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        int num[] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(Print_it(list) / 10);    
}

public static double Print_it(int[] list)
{ 
    int number = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {

        number = number + list[i];
    }
    return(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The for loops should be using the correct test. 'i<=num' will cause an exception when i == num.
2. The "int num[] = scan.nextInt()" statement has illegal syntax.
3. You should be using 'num' wherever you currently use 10, and it should be named 'NUM' to conform to standard Java naming conventions for constants.
4. Print_it (which should be named more like 'printIt') is not printing anything.

Here is a better implementation:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    final static int NUM = 10;

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int[] list = new int[NUM];
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer");
            list[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        printIt(list);
    }

    public static void printIt(int[] list) {
        final int length = list.length;
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            final int n = list[i];
            System.out.println(n);
            total += n;
        }
        System.out.println("Average: " + (double)total / length);
    }
}
```